# Chinese quotes for tattoo

Tags: characters, phrase

I am looking for Chinese quotes or phrases about love, yuanfen, destiny or something along those terms for a tattoo. It’s really hard to find sayings that are really used.

Comment: did you try this one?　https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/30203/are-there-any-free-bilingual-sources-of-chinese-proverb

Comment: You want to express your longing for  "love, yuanfen, destiny" or your belief in them? In short, what do you want to say about them?

Answer (score 2):

生死有命，富贵由天。 
Beckham has a same tattoo.

Answer (score 0):

情不知所起，一往而深 can be translated to :1.Love once begun, will never end.2. Love, a spark from nowhere to eternity.3. We have no idea where our love come from, but we will be devoted to a lifelong love.

It's from a famous Chinese Opera：Peony Pavilion。
created
作者：奥修特白
链接：https://www.zhihu.com/question/53022004/answer/133091432
来源：知乎
著作权归作者所有。商业转载请联系作者获得授权，非商业转载请注明出处。

Answer (score 0):

人生若只如初见 （If Life Was Still as When We First Met）

平生不会相思，才会相思，便害相思。（One don't know love， would love， then love）

陌上花开 可缓缓归矣

不思量，自难忘

此情可待成追忆

Answer (score 0):

千里姻缘一线牵
It means no matter how far away two people live, they will meet and love each other because of the fate.